# C# simplify multiple events to use method

Tags: c#

In my case i have 8 checkbox, each checkbox has click event, if checkbox is clicked, that will call same method like this.

```
    public void _setting(CheckBox check)
        {
         ...
        }
```

And this is the code how click event call the method

```
private void check1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            _setting(check1);
        }
```

How to simplify the click event to call method? Or i have to call like in check1_click until check8?

```
private void check2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                _setting(check2);
            }
private void check3_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                _setting(check3);
            }
...
private void check8_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                _setting(check8);
            }
```

or can it be simplified?

Answer (score 3):

I think so. It seems that `check1`..`check8` are the controls being clicked. In that case, you could assign all events to a single event handler and use the `sender`:

```
private void check_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    _setting((CheckBox)sender);
}
```

If sender is not the control you expect, possibly [`Source`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.routedeventargs.source(v=vs.110).aspx) or [`e.OriginalSource`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.routedeventargs.originalsource(v=vs.110).aspx) is.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void check1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            _setting(sender as CheckBox);
        }
```

This way if you call _setting and sender is not a checkbox, it will be null, not Exception.

Comment: Using `as` will give you no information if something went wrong.